# 403 error when exporting to excel from kartik gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2, export-to-excel

Thanks for your time, hope you can help me.

I'm using Kartik GridView in Yii2, locally I can export the data inside the GridView in any format `(CSV, EXCEL, JSON, PDF)` with no problems. But online I can't export it to EXCEL.

The default action index.php?r=gridview/export/download give the next message in browser:

> You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: This sounds like .htaccess error. Look at the rewrite rules there. If you do not use htaccess, look at the config file of the http server.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

1. Disable the ModSecurity option for the domain in cpanel
2. My domain was protected with Wordfense, so I followed [this guide](https://wp-staging.com/docs/wordfence-plugin-error-403-forbidden-ajax/)
3. ​"Long story short, set Wordfence firewall option to learning mode on the parent site will resolve the ajax error for all of your other websites"

Comment: It would be best if you included relevant contact, rather than using off-site links.